# How to implement opencv selectROI in tkinter?

Tags: python, image, opencv, tkinter, event-handling

I have a image that I want to use it in tkinter and use select ROI function from OpenCv with the mouse events. I have no idea on how to achieve this problem but I tried the best I can, here is my code.
My problem is I have error saying my variable at (lbl tkimgis) is not defined. Is there any other way to achieve this or any suggestions that I can make changes?
Thank you for your help. Have a nice day!

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import PIL.Image as imge
import PIL.ImageTk as imtk

ev = None

def click(event, u16):
    global subregion, tkimgis, ev
    if ev == None:
        ev = event
        return None
    bbox = cv2.selectROI("Image", u16, fromCenter=False)
    cv2.destroyWindow("Image")

    print("region:", bbox)
    ####Here u16 is my image array from another jupyter notebook cell

    tkimgis = imtk.PhotoImage(image=imge.fromarray(u16))
    lbl.config(image=tkimgis)
    (x,y,w,h) = bbox
    subregion = na[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    ev = event
root = Tk()
lbl = Label(root, image=tkimgis)
lbl.place(x=0, y=0)
root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: click(event))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think there is indentation issue in your posted code.

Comment: Hi yes sorry I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code has so many other things that I feel are not done right, So I'll provide a code that you can then carefully study.

In short, you need to run `cv2.selectROI` in a different thread, and then update the label image from the main thread.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from threading import Thread


def display_roi(event):
    global tkimg

    if image:
        tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        cropped_lbl.config(image=tkimg)

def select_roi():
    global image

    img = cv2.imread("sample.png")
    roi  = cv2.selectROI(img)

    imCrop = img[int(roi[1]):int(roi[1]+roi[3]), int(roi[0]):int(roi[0]+roi[2])]
    
    if len(imCrop)>0:
        image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(imCrop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    root.event_generate("<<ROISELECTED>>")

def start_thread():

    thread = Thread(target=select_roi, daemon=True)
    thread.start()


root = tk.Tk()

cropped_lbl = tk.Label(root)
cropped_lbl.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

tk.Button(root, text="select ROI", command=start_thread).pack()

root.bind("<<ROISELECTED>>", display_roi)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I want this ROI feature to only extract the coordinates of the ROI like top(x,y) and the bottom (x,y) so that i can use it to plot values. But I don't understand your code I am new to both tkinter and python so my skills are not that high.

Comment: @Blueman0002 isn't that what `selectROI` returns? so you already have it there, here `roi=cv2.selectROI()`, roi is your bbox.